# read the content of file by getting it from dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have a C# project name as ("Test") which has a class and a folder contains a html file and my senior has compile this project into a dll.

the content of the html file is = "Hello World"

the class contains :

string that read the whole html file.
context.Respone.Write(the string above).

I have another web project which has a page to call the method above by adding the test dll. The question is, how can I read the content of the html file by getting it from the dll ? So that the web page can display "Hello World"

Comment: Can you please close question and mark this as answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your file in Embedded resource and read it using code liek that

```
    public static string GetResourceFileContentAsString(string fileName)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "Your.Namespace." + fileName;

        string resource = null;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                resource = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
```

Comment: can you give the example Your.Namespace. ?

Comment: This is your DLL root namespace + folder structure + your resource file name. For example - if your dll root namespace is "MyProject" and you html file is in subfolder "HtmlResources" then your path to resource will be  "MyProject.HtmlResources.test.html"

Comment: example my project name testing, and it has a subfolder "resources" with a html file "member.html". so, the
var resourceName = "testing.resources.member.html"; ? is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, correct, do not forget to specify Build Action = "Embedded resource" on member.html

Comment: do you have skype ? having some problem on it

Comment: i get null in using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))

Comment: In code i provided as answer - i have var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); but you probably have it inb oter assembly? If yes - you need to get Assembly like that - var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeFormRersources).Assembly

Comment: how to build action on member html

Comment: public static string GetResourceFileContentAsString()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "GameVendor.PT.Resources.MemberLogin.html";
        //var resourceName = "PTGameVendor.Resources.MemberLogin.html";

        string resource = null;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                resource = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }

Comment: In code i provided as answer - i have var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); but you probably have it in other assembly? If yes - you need to get Assembly like that - var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeFormRersources).Assembly

Comment: var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gives you name of current assembly. If your resource is in other assembly this will not work. You need a class with this method in the same assembly as your resource

Comment: Hi, fly_ua , may i know the namespace is actually point to what ? my senior told me that not my project name

Comment: No, just open any file in the root of the project and find the string namespace ... {} This will be you root namespace.Also have a look at this article http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/07/understanding-c-namespaces-and.html

Comment: @testerlol No problem - just mark my post as answer to question and we are done )

Comment: This example is too hard to use

Comment: @fly_ua You' re still helping people after 5 years thanks :)